# Error trying to user oracle db with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

As it says in the Title, I get an exception when trying to run my spring app with the following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.checkpoint.core.repositories.jpa" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[[url]]:[[port]]:[[sid]]" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.checkpoint.core.models.entities" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Setup transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.checkpoint.core.services.impl" />

</beans>
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
Dec 01, 2015 6:17:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy foundorg.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I am new to spring development, so I might have made a lot of mistakes

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I was requested to post my maven dependencies, so here they are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON Processing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Connection Pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Could you show your maven or gradle dependencies?

Comment: Sure, Adding now to question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
```

to:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

As you want to reference the bean, not the String.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I do what you suggested I get the following stacktrace: 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException`

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
 <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

add the above to pom.xml, because you have defined transaction manager bean. You have to satisfy the dependency for the same

Comment: Also I had to define the `hibernate.dialect`, but now it's working